# NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist. while push amplify graphql API

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I am creating graphql API using AWS amplify.
I ran the command and created the schema.graphql, but when I run `Amplify push` I get this error:

> Fetching updates to backend environment: dev from the
>   cloud.(node:21276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchKey: The
>   specified key does not exist.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this issue is 4 months old. Hopefully, you've resolved it by now.

Check the version of Amplify CLI you are using. This error appeared with 4.21.4, and rolling back to 4.21.3 fixed it. The error appears to have returned in 4.29.4, and rolling back to 4.29.0 resolved it for me.

For reference: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4612

Comment: Thanks Upgrading the version helps

Comment: In the case of CI/CD enabled how can I resolve it?